# Please add a :hover rule for #system-message a

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

Currently, the entire system message is a link.

[image: Image of system message]

As a result, it doesn't appear like there is a link in the first place. The fact that the link doesn't react on hover doesn't help.

Would it be possible to add an on-hover effect for that link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added underline on hover for the system message links. should be in the next deployment.